# how to get dropdown value and match with database

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="requesttype"><?php echo $requestField; ?></label>
        <select class="form-control" required="" name="requesttype"  onchange="fcrActionChange(this);">                      
            <option value="">Select Request Type</option>
            <option value="Inquiry">Inquiry</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
            <option value="Service Request/FCR">Service Request/FCR</option>
            <option value="Verification Call">Verification Call</option>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $requestHelp; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the code: 
i want to get the value in other dropdown like if inquiry is selected then in 2nd dropdown the selected values is get and then query is executed.cattype have four types and i want when user select from dropdown then this will happen.anybody kindly help me in this regard.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="catId"><?php echo $categoryField; ?></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="catId">
            <?php
$tcat = "SELECT catId, catName, catType FROM categories WHERE userId = ".$userId." AND isActive = 1 AND catType= ".$_GET['requesttype']." " ;
$rest = mysqli_query($mysqli, $tcat) or die('-2'.mysqli_error());
            ?>
            <option value="..."><?php echo $selectOption; ?></option>
            <?php while ($tcatrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $tcatrow['catId']; ?>"><?php echo  clean($tcatrow['catName']); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $categoryHelp; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do some research on `javascript ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onchange event of first dropdown, use ajax to get data according to first dropdown. And then fill the other.